# Several numpy arrays to single pandas datafram

Tags: python, pandas

I have several numpy arrays:

```py
ema9 = talib.EMA(amzn['Close'].values, 9)
ema10 = talib.EMA(amzn['Close'].values, 10)
ema11 = talib.EMA(amzn['Close'].values, 11)
```

I'd like to get them all organised into a single panda df. How can I do this? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This did it:

single_pandas_df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(list_of_arrays).T)

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your `arrays` in a `list` and do a `pd.concat` -

```
list_of_arrays = [ema9, ema10, ema11]
single_pandas_df = pd.concat(list_of_arrays, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Hi @Mortz - Thanks. But its giving this error: TypeError: 

cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.ndarray'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid.

Kindly help. Thank you.